# it doesn't work when I put setenv clause inside if-end block?

Tags: linux, tcsh

```
#test.tcsh
#!bin/tcsh
setenv A a;
if($argv[1]=="B") then 
  setenv B b;
endif
```

when I perform

```
tcsh  test.tcsh B
echo $B
```

it turn out that

```
undined parameter
```

can you tell me why???

Comment: Child cannot change parent's environment.

Comment: It won't work with `tcsh  test.tcsh A` either. As above, child processes can't change the paren't process environment. In this case your terminal session is the parent, and the `tcsh  test.tcsh` is running as a child to that parent. When it is done, nothing of the child process will be left, unless it writes to a file. (This is how you would have to change the parent environemt). Good luck!

Comment: Use `source test.tcsh` to execute it in the original shell's environment.